# Graphic Card on Gigabyte Aero 15X V8 has slowness

Tags: graphics-card

I have a graphics card problem on my Gigabyte Aero 15X V8, bought just 2 days ago on Amazon.

No game is launched in Ultra quality when I think it can launch them, like Fallout 76 released today.

I updated Windows 10 (1 day to do everything), I updated the drivers (Intel, CG, etc ...), and I flashed the BIOS. Everything looks good, but the PC ramme when I run a game, where I close a full screen on YouTube for example, I do not find it fluid ...

It bothers me to have to send it back, it looks good, the 4K screen is top!

Someone around to help me? Thank you !

Comment: Why did you flash your BIOS? Possibly you just got a card that isn't quick enough for your game.

Comment: Have you installed the display driver from NVIDIA?

Comment: With it being a mobile version GTX 1070 Max-Q, I'm not sure that you'll be able to play new AAA titles in ultra settings like you wish. The GTX 1070 Max-Q is not quite as powerful as a desktop version GTX 1070.